# Python: findatapy to import members of an index data from Bloomberg

Tags: python, finance, bloomberg

I am using the python library findatapy to import data from Bloomberg. 
I want to import the Members of an index(INDX_MEMBERS).

I did some test with others fields and others securities like equity and PX_LAST and it seems that the index is the problem.

My code :

```
from findatapy.util import SwimPool; SwimPool()
from findatapy.market import Market, MarketDataRequest, MarketDataGenerator

market = Market(market_data_generator=MarketDataGenerator())

md_request = MarketDataRequest(start_date='22 Mar 2018',data_source='bloomberg',
                               tickers =['S&P/TSX60 Index'],vendor_tickers =['SPTSX60 Index'],
                               fields=['INDX_MEMBERS'])                               
df = market.fetch_market(md_request)
```

the error :

```
findatapy.market.ioengine - WARNING - Couldn't push MarketDataRequest_373__abstract_curve_key-None__category-None__category_key-backtest_default-cat_bloomberg_daily_NYC__cut-NYC__data_source-bloomberg__environment-backtest__expiry_date-NaT__fields-close__finish_date-2017-04-06
00:00:00__freq-daily__freq_mult-1__gran_freq-None__start_date-2017-01-01 
00:00:00__tickers-test US__trade_side-trade__vendor_fields-PX_LAST__vendor_tickers-SPTSX60 Index to Redis: Error 10061 connecting to 127.0.0.1:6379.
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Please use 'SPTSX60 Index' instead of 'S&P/TSX60 Index'.
2. Please specify what is start_date='22 Mar 2018'? are you trying to pull the index members asof a given date? or the current members? INDX_MEMBERS is not a Historical field.
3. As a suggestion, please use INDX_MWEIGHT_HIST field instead of INDX_MEMBERS, and optionally with END_DATE_OVERRIDE=20180322 (or other day in the past if that is what you are trying to achieve)

Comment: I usually want the current date yes, but will like to be able to run the algo in the past if needed. I didn't find another way then startdate if I had just one date.
The code don't work with (see next comment)

Nonetype object of builtins module is the df output

Comment: md_request = MarketDataRequest(start_date='22 Mar 2018',data_source='bloomberg',
                               tickers =['SPTSX60 Index'],vendor_tickers =['SPTSX60 Index'],
                               fields=['INDX_MWEIGHT_HIST'])

Comment: INDX_MWEIGHT_HIST is not a historical field either, it should not be used in HistoricalDataRequest, but in ReferenceDataRequest with override to return the index components as of a given date in history. From how MarketDataRequest is used above, you pass a value in start_date property, which can direct the function to submit a HistoricalDataRequest to blpapi, which will not work with this field. I'd suggest to try removing start_data and see if you can get the current data, using either INDX_MEMBERS or INDX_MWEIGHT_HIST.

Next step is to find out how to pass overrides to MarketDataRequest().

Comment: Got it, in excel its an BDS and not BDH, Do you have an idea how to call market that way, I tried without the dates,... or with start and end date the same and doesnt work.

Comment: Sorry but I'm not familiar with findatapy library.